# Accessing ROOM DB on main thread

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I am using ROOM DB in my app and my code looks like this -

This is my repo code -

```
override suspend fun storeDataToCache(dataModel: DataModel) {
    //Printing out thread name gives me main thread still
    personalDataDao.insertData(dataModel)
}
```

This is my DAO code -

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertData(dataModel: DataModel)
```

This works.

However when I remove `suspend` keyword it gives me -

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on 
the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

which is totally fine because I am trying to access ROOM DB on main thread.

But my question is, with `suspend` keyword and without doing thread switch for eg. `withContext(Dispatchers.Default)`, how does it work? Does ROOM DB internally perform all its operations on worker thread?

Comment: If you want queries to be executed on main thread add `.allowMainThreadQueries()` while building database `Room.databaseBuilder(this, MyAppDatabase::class.java, "MyAppDatabase").allowMainThreadQueries().build()` but its not recommended . So room is not just restricted to worker thread

Comment: may I ask why you want to use your db the main thread ?

Comment: don't use db transaction on the main thread

Answer (score 0):

You have to set ***allowMainThreadQueries()*** at time of creating instance of RoomDatabase class

```
INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
   context.getApplicationContext(), 
   AppDatabase.class, 
   "my_database")
.allowMainThreadQueries()  // add this line
.build();
```

Comment: I think its not a good idea to do DB operations on main thread. However I found an article that explains my question - https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-coroutines-422b786dc4c5 . Adding suspend to your dao method will ensure the operation happens on background thread

Comment: yes, but in your case if you want to use without suspend means that access in main thread and if you want to access in background than you must have to use suspend

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
// Create a file storage based database
INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            CustomerRoomDatabase.class, "customer_database")
                            .build();

// Create an in-memory database
INSTANCE = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            CustomerRoomDatabase.class)
                            .build();﻿
```

or

```
INSTANCE = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                                CustomerRoomDatabase.class)
                              .allowMainThreadQueries().build();﻿
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you mark the function as suspend, Room executes the query in a background/worker thread and then resumes the calling coroutine with the results (or exception) when it's done.
Which means you don't need to do stuff like `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { }` and you can just call the function directly.